# How to add a proxy settings to gem

Tags: proxy, ruby, rails

Does Ubuntu have default proxy settings? I ask this question because every time I try to install rails through `gem install rails` I get connection timed out error! This error occurs even I try from live cd! So I am in doubt if Ubuntu has some default proxy settings.

Comment: Are you sure that isn't the mirror who is dead? What exactly throws a timeout?

Comment: the connection to https://rubygems.org but when I removed it from the gem sources and added http://rubygems.org worked smoothly !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could solve this problem by adding http://rubygems.org to sources of my gem. 
Also I removed https://rubygems.org from it.

Answer (score 0):

goto networks -> network proxy -> manual

Enter your proxy and port

Hit apply system wide

Comment: Yes it does. Even if it is probably wrong, it does try to answer the question. If it is technically wrong, it should be downvoted, not deleted.

Comment: @ArUn I don't ask to set proxy. I ask if there is a default proxy setting in Ubuntu. Anyway thanks a lot for your trial to help me.